# Error when attempting to read heart rate from Watch

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to build an app that reads the heart rate data from HealthKit and displays it in a table, but whenever I run the code I have it terminates because it finds a nil in the following method:

extension InterfaceController: HeartRateDelegate {

```
func heartRateUpdated(heartRateSamples: [HKSample]) {

    guard let heartRateSamples = heartRateSamples as? [HKQuantitySample] else {
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.heartRateSamples = heartRateSamples
        guard let sample = heartRateSamples.first else {
            return
        }
        let value = sample.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit(from: "count/min"))
        let heartRateString = String(format: "%.00f", value)
        self.heartRateLabel.setText(heartRateString)//where it finds the nil
    }
}
```

is there a way to wrap that line in an optional? it probably goes without saying but I'm pretty new to iOS programming

EDIT: heartRateLabel is an outlet that I've connected in my storyboard (this is all in the watch interface controller), but I don't think I've initialized it properly. In the Interface Controller class I've written:

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

```
@IBOutlet var heartRateLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

@IBOutlet var workoutButton: WKInterfaceButton!

let healthKitManager = HealthKitManager.sharedInstance 

var isWorkoutInProgress = false

var workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession?

var workoutStartDate: Date?

var heartRateQuery: HKQuery?

var heartRateSamples: [HKQuantitySample] = [HKQuantitySample]()
```

would I need to initialize it in this step? what would the syntax be?

Comment: Is `heartRateLabel` an optional? i.e. is it initialized as a `UILabel?` ?

Comment: When you do this print(value) what you are getting?

Comment: Is heartRateLabel an outlet?  Have you connected it in your storyboard?

Comment: @Paolo I've edited the code to show where I've initialized heartRateLabel in Interface Controller